# Faster way to create a list of lists for multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wanna try if my code gets faster by using multiprocessing.

The Problem is my function will have multiple arguments, so a solution that I found is creating a list of lists. Is this the fastest way? 
Is there a better way than mine with the while loop ?

Here my code:

```
def add(a, b, c):
    x = a + b + c
    print(x)


CPUS = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
WORKERS = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=CPUS)

Tasklist1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Tasklist2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Tasklist3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

a = []
i = 0
while i < len(Tasklist1):
    a.append([Tasklist1[i], Tasklist2[i], Tasklist3[i]])
    i += 1


WORKERS.starmap(add, a)
```

Comment: Is this an example code or the problem you want to solve?

Comment: example code of course

Comment: I just tried the same for my main Program its 100 times slower, than with single core. Creating these big Tasklists costs too much resources..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a user of MultiProcessing(yet), but you can just use `zip` to do so.

```
list1 = [i for i in range(10000)]
list2 = [i for i in range(10000)]
list3 = [i for i in range(10000)]

result = [(i+j+k) for i,j,k in zip(list1,list2,list3)]

%timeit [(i+j+k) for i,j,k in zip(list1,list2,list3)]
1.23 ms ± 85.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```